# Проблема в QLabеl

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть две строки: `'какие-то слова\n'` и `'еще что-то'`. Хочу записать их в QLabel. И она так и записывается. Почему? Ведь должно так:

> ```
> какие-то слова
> еще что-то
> ```

Вместо:

`'какие-то слова\n'` и `'еще что-то'`

Или QLable так не умеет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите как одну строку - с символом `\n` включитеъно:

```
какие-то слова\nеще что-то
```

в Qt Designer,

или присвойте к свойству `text` объекта типа QLabel например так:

```
first_line = 'какие-то слова'
second_line = 'еще что-то'

qLabel_object.text = first_line + '\n' + secnd_line
```